# The annihilator of a normed vector space

Tags: functional-analysis

Given a normed vector space $X$, consider a subspace $Z$ of its continuous dual $X^{\ast}$. I want to show that if the annihilator of $Z$ is zero, then $Z$ is $weak^{\ast}ly$ dense in $X^{\ast}$. How should I prove this?

I'd like to use Hahn Banach, probably a version of it for locally convex topological space, since we are not considering the norm topology on $X^{\ast}$. Also, I should probably prove by contradiction.

Comment: In any locally convex space $Y$ a subspace $L$ is dense if and only if its annihilator $L^\perp=\{y^*\in Y^*: y^*|_L=0\}$ is $0$. Apply this to $Y=X^*$ with the weak$^*$ topology whose dual is $X$ (more precisely, every element of the dual is an evaluation in a point of $X$).